# SAML2 httpcontext is already authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to build an ASPNet SAML2 orientated WebApp and i'm facing issues. I'm using the ITFoxtec library to handle all the process but i'm struggling when a user is trying to reconnect on the webapp.
The scenario that causes the issue is the following:

1. Launch WebApp on a linux serveur on port 49500
2. Connect to the WebApp thanks to IE on a Windows session through the route "Auth/Login"
3. Token is generated and accessible
4. Try to regenerate once more the token through the route "Auth/Login"

And at this point, the WebApp trigger the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There already exist an Authenticated user.
> at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore.Saml2ResponseExtensions.CreateSession(Saml2AuthnResponse saml2AuthnResponse, HttpContext httpContext, Nullable`1 lifetime, Boolean isPersistent, Func`2 claimsTransform) in C:\XXXXX\ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2-0c0cef05050d633f000be9399dc6a5b1a009a6da\src\ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore\Extensions\Saml2ResponseExtensions.cs:line 24

After digging a little bit inside the ITFoxted code, the error is triggered by the `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` being set to `True` when it's run on Linux. I've also seen that on the first iteration, `HttpContext.User.Identity.AuthenticationType` is set to `null` and on the second iteration it is set to `Federation`.
I have done multiple test on multiple environnment and i've end up with the following notes:

1. Running the WebApp on Windows with a local pfx works (even with multiple refresh)
2. Running the WebApp on Windows the AuthenticationType is never set to Federation

Listed below are the code for launching the `WebApp` and the `AuthController`.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[EnableCors("SAML_CORS")]
[Route("Auth")]
public class SamlController : Controller
{
    const string relayStateReturnUrl = "ReturnUrl";
    const string ClaimMatricule = "matricule";
    const string WebappsJwtRequest = "getJwt=true";
    const string WebappsJwtFailure = "jwt=FAILED";
    private readonly Saml2Configuration config;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public SamlController(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<Saml2Configuration> configAccessor)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
        config = configAccessor.Value;
    }

    [Route("Metadata")]
    public ObjectResult Metadata()
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificates.Import(Configuration["Saml2:SigningCertificateFile"], null, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        var cert = certificates[0];
        string publicSigingKey = Convert.ToBase64String(cert.RawData);
        
        string metadataTemplate = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Configuration["Jwt:SpMetadataFilePath"]);

        metadataTemplate = metadataTemplate.Replace("PUBLIC_RSA_SHA1_SIGNING_CERTIFICATE", publicSigingKey);
        metadataTemplate = metadataTemplate.Replace("USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE", Configuration["Saml2:ClaimIdentifierName"]);

        string fullHostName = Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName.ToLower();
        if (!Configuration.GetSection("CustomIssuer").GetChildren().Any(item => item.Key == fullHostName))
        {
            fullHostName = "localhost";
        }
        metadataTemplate = metadataTemplate.Replace("ISSUER_TO_REPLACE", Configuration["CustomIssuer:" + fullHostName]);

        string currentUrl = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
        metadataTemplate = metadataTemplate.Replace("SAML_ASSERTION_CONSUMPTION_ENDPOINT", $"https://{currentUrl}/Auth/AssertionConsumerService");

        return new ObjectResult(metadataTemplate)
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }

    [Route("Login")]
    public object Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
        binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

        if (returnUrl != null && returnUrl.Contains(WebappsJwtFailure))
        {
            return View();
        }

        if (returnUrl != null && returnUrl.Contains(WebappsJwtRequest))
        {
            return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
            {
                ForceAuthn = true,
            }).RedirectLocation.ToString();
        }
        return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)
        {
            ForceAuthn = true,
        }).ToActionResult();

    }

    [Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
    {

        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

        binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);

        var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
        var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");

        if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success) {
            var failureReason = $"Unsuccessful SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}";
            Console.WriteLine(failureReason);
            returnUrl = returnUrl.Contains(WebappsJwtRequest) ? returnUrl.Replace(WebappsJwtRequest, $"jwt=FAILED({failureReason})") : $"{returnUrl}?jwt=FAILED";
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
        var samlContent = await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));
        var claims = samlContent.Claims;
        var matricule = claims.Where(c => c.Type == Configuration["Saml2:ClaimIdentifierName"]).First().Value;
        var jwt = this.GenerateJWT(matricule);         

        if (returnUrl.Contains(WebappsJwtRequest))
        {
            // If this endpoint is used as an API by the proxy SAML web app, then we need to send the JWT token to it
            returnUrl = returnUrl.Replace(WebappsJwtRequest, "jwt=" + jwt);
        }

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    [HttpPost("Logout")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
        }

        var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
        var saml2LogoutRequest = await new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, User).DeleteSession(HttpContext);
        return Redirect("~/");
    }

    private string GenerateJWT(String userMatricule)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);

        string fullHostName = Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName.ToLower();
        if (!Configuration.GetSection("CustomIssuer").GetChildren().Any(item => item.Key == fullHostName))
        {
            fullHostName = "localhost";
        }
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
          Configuration["CustomIssuer:" + fullHostName],
          Configuration["CustomIssuer:" + fullHostName],
          new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimMatricule, userMatricule) },
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Double.Parse(Configuration["Jwt:ValidityDurationInMinutes"])),
          signingCredentials: credentials
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

Below, the launcher:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                // custom config file
                .AddJsonFile(IdentifyJsonConf(), optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                .Build();
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args, configuration).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, IConfiguration conf)
    {
        
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWebRoot("wwwroot_saml")
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ListenAnyIP(int.Parse(conf["Port"]), listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(conf["Saml2:SigningCertificateFile"]);
                });
            })
            .UseConfiguration(conf)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    private static string IdentifyJsonConf()
    {
        string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        // On récupère le chemin du fichier de config (Linbux par defaut)
        var confPath = @"xxxxxx";
        var confFile = "xxxx.json";

        var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        var configFileLinux = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir, confFile));

        if (!configFileLinux.Exists)
        {
            configFileLinux = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(confPath, confFile));
        }

        // On recupere l'OS afin de determiner quel fichier de config utiliser
        OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
        PlatformID pid = os.Platform;
        switch (pid)
        {
            // Si on est sur du Windows, alors c'est pour du test
            case PlatformID.Win32NT:
            case PlatformID.Win32S:
            case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
            case PlatformID.WinCE:
                Console.WriteLine("Getting xxxx.json config file because running on Windows!");

                confFile = "xxxxx.json";
                var configFileWindows = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, confFile));

                if (!configFileWindows.Exists)
                {
                    configFileWindows = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir, confFile));
                }
                configFileLinux = configFileWindows;
                break;
            // Si on est sur du Linux
            case PlatformID.Unix:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return configFileLinux.Name;
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Is it a solution to add a `IsAuthenticated` check in the `AuthController` `Login` method?

Like this:

```
[Route("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
    }

    var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
    binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

    ... more code ...
```

Comment: Adding this code to the login correctly trigger the if section. Nevertheless, it end up on a not found page. The page it's trying to reach seems strange for me as it is trying to go to "myhostname/<!doctype%20html>...". It seems the Redirect adds the HTML directly to the end of the url. Is it the correct way to redirect? Thanks :)

Comment: It should redirect to the root of your web site. I expect it to be the same on a linux platform. But you can try to select a specifik page.

Comment: Do you think it might be because the function Login for me returns an object and not the  IActionResult as you precise in your exemple?

Comment: Maybe, I have newer tried that in a page controller.

Comment: Our architecture is that the WebApp is used to redirect the user to a JWT generation. The login section execute a GET request to obtain this token. If i had this part of code inside the Login section, wouldn't it just redirect me to the index and do nothing? Isn't it supposed to automaticaly regenerate a token?
The main focus is that our WebApp just served as an entrypoint for generating the token.

Comment: do you have any idea...?

Comment: No I do not have any idea about that...